# Twilio Studio Flow - Errors with recording calls?

Tags: twilio

I am working through an issue with Twilio Studio Flow.

From a high level, the flow is triggered by a webhook after it kicks off, it does the following:

1. Dials a known phone number
2. Prompts the user to "press 1 to continue"
3. After they press 1 calls another phone number, bridging the calls
4. Calls a webhook after the call is completed

Flow setup[image: Twilio Studio Flow]

This all works fine, except I'm not able to access the call recording.

Often times the flow logs show the recordingSID as nothing, and I cant sort out the reason why.

The widget/event 'Connect Call To' has two possible outcomes 'call completed' and 'hangup' (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#connect-call-to). The documentation makes no reference as to why or what these outcomes actually are.

To further confuse things, there are some instances where the 'hangup' event fires and i get a recordingSID, and some instances where the 'call completed' event fires and i get a recording SID. (And many times for both, where i don't get a recording SID').

I've had no luck with twilio support on getting an answer. Has anyone encountered this issue, were you able to work around it? I think it may be a bug in the platform.

Answer (score 0):

For the Connect Call To Widget, "Call completed" refers to the child leg and "Hangup" refers to the parent leg (the caller).

Unfortunately, it is hard to tell the operational flow based on your description.